# debug views and layout in `react-native`

Tags: debugging, react-native

I'd like to have an obvious way to see my view hierarchy.

In web development I could do that with:

```
body * { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}
```

This gives me nice visual rectangles and an illusion of depth.

In native development there is the [exploding 3d view](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html) of the hierarchy.

- Can I connect the xcode view hierarchy debugger somehow? -- EDIT: yes. just open and run the project from xcode
- Is there a `StyleSheet` rule I can write that will cascade down to children and make their position and size obvious?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the xcode view hierarchy debugger and its pretty simple to do. You should just open xcodeproj(probably location of xcodeproj is inside of ios folder), run program from xcode(product -> run, or just cmd+r) and then you will be able to use native view debugger.